# Create a Rolling Days and Monthly Table using html table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, html-table, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID     Date1                     T1     Date2     Val1
A-1    2018-01-10 15:05:24       A    2018-01-15  10
A-2    2018-01-05 14:15:22       B    2018-01-14  12
A-3    2018-01-04 13:20:21       A    2018-01-13  15
A-4    2018-01-01 18:35:45       B    2018-01-12  22
A-5    2017-12-28 19:45:10       A    2018-01-11  18
A-6    2017-12-10 08:03:29       A    2018-01-10  21
A-7    2017-12-06 20:55:55       A    2018-01-09  28
A-8    2018-01-10 10:02:12       A    2018-01-15  10
A-9    2018-01-05 17:15:14       B    2018-01-14  12
A-10   2018-01-04 18:35:58       A    2018-01-13  15
A-11   2018-01-01 21:09:25       B    2018-01-12  22
A-12   2017-12-28 02:12:22       A    2018-01-11  18
A-13   2017-12-10 03:45:44       A    2018-01-10  21
A-14   2017-12-06 07:15:25       A    2018-01-09  28
```

From the above dataframe i want to create a small below mentioned dataframe and convert it in to htmltable format that can easily e-mail through using `mailR` library.

[image]

```
Conditions:
1. Consider `Date2` for the `# of A` and `# of B` For both Date and month report.
2. `# of A` mean count of where `T1` is A for the same date and month. (same for B)
3. `Sum of A` mean sum of `Val1` for the same date and month. (same for B).
4. `Average of A` means Average of where `T1` is A for the same date and month. (same for B)
5. `Avg Time A` means Average of `Date2`-`Date1` value for "A" for the same date and month. (same for B)
6. I want these date for the last 7 days rolling back based on date available in Dataframe. (In dataframe data should be of 365 days but i want image for only last seven days rolling back)
7. For `A & B Consolidated` # of A and sum of B should be as per same logic but for month considering `Date2`.
8. For `MOM Growth` the Formula would be (i.e =(Feb-18-Jan-18)/Jan-18 in % (-) if negative)
9. `A & B Consolidated` should also be in 7 month rolling and it should automatically change the month if 8th month comes from first day.
```

Comment: @akrun Is this possible through R???

Comment: note that you cannot reference people that haven't involved themselves in your question - they don't get notified. Of course anything's possible, but this looks like some work and you should definitely share your attempts

Comment: @RolandASc ohh sorry, i didn't know that...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `dplyr`, `lubridate`, and `tableHTML`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tableHTML)
```

I use a `data.frame` called `my_data` which looks like this:

```
my_data <- read.table(text = 
                      "ID     Date1                     T1     Date2     Val1
                      A-1    '2018-01-10 15:05:24'       A    2018-01-15  10
                      A-2    '2018-01-05 14:15:22'       B    2018-01-14  12
                      A-3    '2018-01-04 13:20:21'       A    2018-01-13  15
                      A-4    '2018-01-01 18:35:45'       B    2018-01-12  22
                      A-5    '2017-12-28 19:45:10'       A    2018-01-11  18
                      A-6    '2017-12-10 08:03:29'       A    2018-01-10  21
                      A-7    '2017-12-06 20:55:55'       A    2018-01-09  28
                      A-8    '2018-01-10 10:02:12'       A    2018-01-15  10
                      A-9    '2018-01-05 17:15:14'       B    2018-01-14  12
                      A-10   '2018-01-04 18:35:58'       A    2018-01-13  15
                      A-11   '2018-01-01 21:09:25'       B    2018-01-12  22
                      A-12   '2017-12-28 02:12:22'       A    2018-01-11  18
                      A-13   '2017-12-10 03:45:44'       A    2018-01-10  21
                      A-14   '2017-12-06 07:15:25'       A    2018-01-09  28",
                      header = TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I then change the date fields to `POSIXct` and `Date`, group by `Date2`, and summarise the data as described. This is done for both `A` and `B`. The 2 resulting structures are then merged, `NA`s are replaced with an empty string.

```
table_1 <- merge(
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date1 = lubridate::ymd_hms(Date1),
           Date2 = lubridate::ymd(Date2)) %>%
    filter(T1 == "A") %>% 
    group_by(Date2) %>%
    summarise("# of A" = n(),
              "sum of A" = sum(Val1),
              "Average of A" = mean(Val1),
              "Avg  Time A" = round(mean(difftime(Date2, Date1)), 2)),
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date1 = lubridate::ymd_hms(Date1),
           Date2 = lubridate::ymd(Date2)) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "B") %>% 
    group_by(Date2) %>%
    summarise("# of B" = n(),
              "sum of B" = sum(Val1),
              "Average of B" = mean(Val1),
              "Avg  Time B" = round(mean(difftime(Date2, Date1)), 2))
  , by = "Date2",
  all = TRUE) 

table_1[is.na(table_1)] <- ""
```

I then use `tableHTML` to create an HTML table:

```
table_1 %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            widths = rep(100, 9),
            second_headers = list(c(1, 4, 4),
                                  c("", "Status of A", "Status of B")))
```

Which looks like this:
[image: table_1]

Next, I use the same logic with a few teaks:

- the data is sorted by `Date2`
- only `# of A|B` and `sum of A|B` are used
- `lag()` is used to get MOM changes

```
table_2 <- merge(  
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2)) %>% 
    arrange(Date2) %>% 
    mutate(Month = paste(month(ymd_hms(Date1), label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-")) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "A") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of A" = n(),
              "sum of A" = sum(Val1)) %>%
    mutate("MOM Growth # of A" = round(apply(cbind(`# of A`, lag(- `# of A`)), 
                                       1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of A`), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of A" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of A`, lag(- `sum of A`)), 
                                         1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of A`) * 100, 2)) %>% 
    select(Month, `# of A`, `MOM Growth # of A`, `sum of A`, `MOM Growth sum of A`),
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2)) %>% 
    arrange(Date2) %>% 
    mutate(Month = paste(month(ymd_hms(Date1), label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-")) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "B") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of B" = n(),
              "sum of B" = sum(Val1)) %>%
    mutate("MOM Growth # of B" = round(apply(cbind(`# of B`, lag(- `# of B`)), 
                                       1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of B` * 100), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of B" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of B`, lag(- `sum of B`)), 
                                         1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of B`) * 100), 2) %>%
    select(Month, `# of B`, `MOM Growth # of B`, `sum of B`, `MOM Growth sum of B`),
  by = "Month",
  all = TRUE)

table_2[is.na(table_2)] <- ""
```

Again using `tableHTML`:

```
table_2 %>% tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
                      widths = rep(100, 9),
                     second_headers = list(c(1, 4, 4),
                                           c("", "Status of A", "Status of B")),
                     caption = "A & B consolidated") %>% 
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border"), 
                             c("bold", "1px solid black")))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"Date2 = lubridate::ymd(Date2 )) %>% str()
filter"

Comment: Got the error: Removed `str()` from `Date2 = lubridate::ymd(Date2)) %>% str()` and it worked.

Comment: Just a small issue here for `table_2` the Month are in unstructured (i.e oct-17, dec-17,nov-17, feb-18, jan-18 etc.)

Comment: Can you elaborate further what you mean with 'the Month are unstructured'? I have used `arrange()` to make sure that dates are in order.

Comment: I mean in month column the month should be either in ascending order or descending order of Month but its coming uneven, i'm checking and i think there are some issue in `MOM Growth` column as well.

Comment: At the moment, it is Dec 2017 followed by Jan 2018, which seems ok to me, what would you change here?

Comment: Yes but it's uneven on large dataset...i'll take care of it. Can you please help me one here i just want to show these data on 7 Day rolling for Date and Month. If you have quick solution for this other wise i'm working on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165513/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-clemens).

Comment: how can i prepare `table_1` in date sequence format...I mean where there is no data available for particular date add row for that date with all field as 0 or NA. For example if I have data for 2018-01-10 and than 2018-01-12 than add row for 2018-01-11 as well with all field as 0 or NA.

Comment: @VectorJX That wouldn't be possible may be.

Comment: @Roy1245 I think so...:(

Comment: To get all dates between min and max, just create a a sequence and merge it with table 1: table_1 <- merge(data.frame(Date2 = seq(min(ymd(my_data$Date2)),
                                        max(ymd(my_data$Date2)),
                                        by = "days")),
                 table_1,
                 by = "Date2",
                 all = TRUE)

Comment: @clemens Thanks....:) I'm also trying to add `Average of A` , `Avg Time A` and `Average of B` , `Average Time B` in `table_2`. with the existing data, the same `table_1` rule will be applicable there.????

Comment: It probably will.

Comment: @clemens I'm confuse a bit at this line: `mutate("MOM Growth # of A" = round(apply(cbind(`# of A`, lag(- `# of A`)), 
                                       1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of A`), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of A" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of A`, lag(- `sum of A`)), 
                                         1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of A`) * 100, 2)) %>% 
    select(Month, `# of A`, `MOM Growth # of A`, `sum of A`, `MOM Growth sum of A`),` How to tweak the `table_1` code here in `table_2` for the calculation on Month basis.

Comment: you would have to calculate it in the `summarise()` part.

Comment: @clemens I have tried copy this here in `summarise()`: ``$ Disbursal` = sum(Loan_Amount),
              `Average Ticket Size` = mean(Loan_Amount),` but getting some error.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow, I would suggest to post a new question with this additional feature.

Comment: @clemens Thanks....Posted a new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909097/calculating-average-and-median-on-monthly-data-and-convert-in-htmltable-r

Comment: @clemens Please answer the new posted question.