# Calculating Average and median on Monthly data and convert in htmltable R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, html-table, dplyr

I have a DF:

```
my_data <- read.table(text = 
                      "ID     Date1                     T1     Date2     Val1
                      A-1    '2018-01-10 15:05:24'       A    2018-01-15  10
                      A-2    '2018-01-05 14:15:22'       B    2018-01-14  12
                      A-3    '2018-01-04 13:20:21'       A    2018-01-13  15
                      A-4    '2018-01-01 18:35:45'       B    2018-01-12  22
                      A-5    '2017-12-28 19:45:10'       A    2018-01-11  18
                      A-6    '2017-12-10 08:03:29'       A    2018-01-10  21
                      A-7    '2017-12-06 20:55:55'       A    2018-01-09  28
                      A-8    '2018-01-10 10:02:12'       A    2018-01-15  10
                      A-9    '2018-01-05 17:15:14'       B    2018-01-14  12
                      A-10   '2018-01-04 18:35:58'       A    2018-01-13  15
                      A-11   '2018-01-01 21:09:25'       B    2018-01-12  22
                      A-12   '2017-12-28 02:12:22'       A    2018-01-11  18
                      A-13   '2017-12-10 03:45:44'       A    2018-01-10  21
                      A-14   '2017-12-06 07:15:25'       A    2018-01-09  28 
                      A-18   '2017-10-07 08:02:84        B    2017-11-05  20
                      A-21   '2017-10-01 06:04:04        A    2017-10-20  15
                      A-51   '2017-09-20 08:07:06        A    2017-09-28  10
                      A-35   '2017-09-14 08:02:45        A    2017-09-25  20
                      A-30   '2017-08-10 15:03:08        A    2017-08-30  25", 
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and running below mentioned code i get output as shown in below:

```
    table_2 <- merge(  
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2)) %>% 
    arrange(Date2) %>% 
    mutate(Month = paste(month(ymd_hms(Date1), label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-")) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "A") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of A" = n(),
              "sum of A" = sum(Val1)) %>%
    mutate("MOM Growth # of A" = round(apply(cbind(`# of A`, lag(- `# of A`)), 
                                       1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of A`), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of A" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of A`, lag(- `sum of A`)), 
                                         1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of A`) * 100, 2)) %>% 
    select(Month, `# of A`, `MOM Growth # of A`, `sum of A`, `MOM Growth sum of A`),
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2)) %>% 
    arrange(Date2) %>% 
    mutate(Month = paste(month(ymd_hms(Date1), label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-")) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "B") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of B" = n(),
              "sum of B" = sum(Val1)) %>%
    mutate("MOM Growth # of B" = round(apply(cbind(`# of B`, lag(- `# of B`)), 
                                       1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of B` * 100), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of B" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of B`, lag(- `sum of B`)), 
                                         1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of B`) * 100), 2) %>%
    select(Month, `# of B`, `MOM Growth # of B`, `sum of B`, `MOM Growth sum of B`),
  by = "Month",
  all = TRUE)

table_2[is.na(table_2)] <- ""
```

Output (table_2):

[image]

Now i want to add two more column `Median of A` , `Avg Time of A` under `Status of A` head and `Median of B`, `Avg Time of B` in `Status of B` head. and convert those output in htmltable format.

Just wanted to know how to tweak code in `summarise` to calculate these value on monthly data.

in addition, month should be in sequence order in output data & if there is any month missing between `Max` month and `Min` month than that month should come with all value 0 except `MOM Growth` for both `Status of A` and `Status of B` because that should be than -100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tableHTML)
```

I have added a median and avg time column for `A` and `B`, plus added the `MOM Growth` condition, and ensured that the Months are 1) in the correct order and 2) complete, even if no data is available in a particular month.

In order to get all Months, create a date sequence from the first to the last date in your data (with 1 month step in between). Then make sure both groups `A` and `B` have a date (because there is a filter later on):

```
date_range = expand.grid(Date1 = seq(min(ymd_hms(my_data$Date1)), max(ymd_hms(my_data$Date1)), 
                                     by = "1 month"),
                         T1 = c("A", "B"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table_2 <- merge( 
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2),
           Date1 = ymd_hms(Date1)) %>% 
    full_join(date_range, by = c("Date1", "T1")) %>% # join date ranges to table
    arrange(Date1) %>% # sort by date
    mutate(Month = paste(month(Date1, label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-"),
           row_number = row_number(), # create row_numbers to keep up order
           Val1 = coalesce(Val1, 0L)) %>% # replace NA with 0 in Val1
    filter(T1 == "A") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of A" = n(),
              "sum of A" = sum(Val1, na.rm = TRUE),
              "Median of A" = median(Val1, na.rm = TRUE), # compute median
              "Avg Time of A" = round(mean(difftime(Date2, Date1),
                                           na.rm = TRUE), # compute avg time
                                      2),
              row_number = min(row_number)) %>% # get min row number
    arrange(row_number) %>% # sort by row number (to sort months)
    mutate("MOM Growth # of A" = round(apply(cbind(`# of A`, lag(- `# of A`)), 
                                             1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of A`), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of A" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of A`, lag(- `sum of A`)), 
                                               1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of A`) * 100, 2)) %>% 
    mutate("MOM Growth # of A" = if_else(is.infinite(`MOM Growth # of A`), 100, `MOM Growth # of A`), # replace Inf with 100
           "MOM Growth sum of A" = if_else(is.infinite(`MOM Growth sum of A`), 100, `MOM Growth sum of A`)) %>% 
    select(Month, `# of A`, `MOM Growth # of A`,
           `sum of A`, `MOM Growth sum of A`,
           `Median of A`, `Avg Time of A`), 
  my_data %>% 
    mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date2),
           Date1 = ymd_hms(Date1)) %>% 
    full_join(date_range, by = c("Date1", "T1")) %>% 
    arrange(Date1) %>% 
    mutate(Month = paste(month(Date1, label = TRUE), year(Date1), sep = "-"),
           row_number = row_number(),
           Val1 = coalesce(Val1, 0L)) %>% 
    filter(T1 == "B") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise("# of B" = n(),
              "sum of B" = sum(Val1, na.rm = TRUE),
              "Median of B" = median(Val1, na.rm = TRUE),
              "Avg Time of B" = round(mean(difftime(Date2, Date1),
                                           na.rm = TRUE),
                                      2),
              row_number = min(row_number)) %>%
    arrange(row_number) %>% 
    mutate("MOM Growth # of B" = round(apply(cbind(`# of B`, lag(- `# of B`)), 
                                             1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`# of B`), 2),
           "MOM Growth sum of B" = round(apply(cbind(`sum of B`, lag(- `sum of B`)), 
                                               1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) / lag(`sum of B`) * 100, 2)) %>% 
    mutate("MOM Growth # of B" = if_else(is.infinite(`MOM Growth # of B`), 100, `MOM Growth # of B`),
           "MOM Growth sum of B" = if_else(is.infinite(`MOM Growth sum of B`), 100, `MOM Growth sum of B`)) %>% 
    select(Month, `# of B`, `MOM Growth # of B`,
           `sum of B`, `MOM Growth sum of B`,
           `Median of B`, `Avg Time of B`), 
  by = "Month", 
  all = TRUE,
  sort = FALSE) # do not sort by ID column to keep month order
```

'Remove' missing values:

```
table_2[is.na(table_2)] = ""
```

Create a `tableHTML` from that data:

```
table_2 %>% tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
                      widths = rep(100, 13),
                      second_headers = list(c(1, 4, 4),
                                            c("", "Status of A", "Status of B")),
                      caption = "A & B consolidated") %>% 
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border"), 
                             c("bold", "1px solid black")))
```

And this is the result:
[image: tableHTML output]

Comment: it might be an idea to replace `n()` with `sum(!is.na(Date2))` when counting the number of rows, since you would also count the empty rows.

Comment: This error i'm getting : `Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'date_range' not found`

Comment: did you run the first lines of that code junk as well?

Comment: Now this error: `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Argument 2 must be type double, not integer`

Comment: With the data I am using, `Val1` is an integer. In your case it seems to be different. The problem comes from `coalesce()`. Just replace `0L` with `0` and it should work

Comment: I want a `date_range` on `Date2` instead of `Date1` and when i'm trying to do so i'm getting this error: `Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite`

Comment: not sure what's going on there, since I don't know what r1, t0, ... are

Comment: How can i just create `date_range` with `Date2` by Replacing `Date1` Right??

Comment: date_range = expand.grid(Date1 = seq(min(ymd(my_data$Date2)), max(ymd(my_data$Date2)), 
                                     by = "1 month"),
                         T1 = c("A", "B"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: Now here we are facing the same issue as previous, the Month are coming uneven now, is it because of `ymd_hms` or something else??

Comment: How to add light blue color in first three row in htmltable.

Comment: that's the caption. use `add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color"),
                             c("lightblue")))` instead

Comment: At `# of A` and `# of B` column it automatically add +1 (i.e if actual number is 5 than it show as 6 in `# of A` and `# of B` column).

Comment: That's because you have at least one record per month even if you don't have any data. change `"# of A" = n()` to `"# of A" = sum(!is.na(Date1))` or `"# of A" = sum(!is.na(Date2))` (whichever is not used in `date_range`)

Comment: Please suggest me how to join both table with a space between two table. i'm using `abc<-paste(table_1,table_2, collapse = "<br>")` but it didn't work.

Comment: paste(table_1,
      '<br>',
      table_2, 
      collapse = '/n') %>% 
  tableHTML:::print.tableHTML()

Comment: check out the vignettes, this is the tutorial: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html if you want to find out more just use `vignette(package = "tableHTML")`

Comment: How to make last row in Bold with Light Yellow background color for any htmlTable (i.e for example Table_1)

Comment: I'm trying this:`add_css_row(css = list('background-color', '#f2f2f2'),'bold',
                 rows = even(8)) %>%`

Comment: you should open new questions instead of following up in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165896/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-clemens).

Comment: Can you check one last thing here, it take Median as `# of A` +1 (i.e `Median of A` as total Val1/`# of A`+1)

Comment: To understand it simple if My Val1 is 30 against 10 `# of A` than it should come as 3 but it coming 2.72 (30/11).